# Laravel 5 - hide warnings

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, xampp, mamp

I want to disable the php warnings like:

```
ErrorException in …/app/helpers/session.php line 34:
Undefined  property: stdClass::$type (View:
…/resources/views/partials/header.blade.php)
(View: …
```

I use: Laravel 5
I have tested: MAMP, MAMP Pro, XAMPP

APP_DEBUG: false dosen´t work
ERROR_REPORTING(0) dosen´t work

Comment: What's so bad about fixing it, instead of hiding it? :)

Comment: Exceptions aren't errors, so they need to be fixed.

Comment: I am the only person with this error. It works fine on all other server/computer